# Can code injection take place from the function CreateODBCDate()?

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, sql-injection

If data returned by `CreateODBCDate` is being used in SQL queries, should I sanitize the returned value or is that not necessary? Here's the [official documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_19.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sanitation needed for CreateODBCDate, but make use of `<cfqueryparam>` and take advantage of both security (built-in validation) and performance (prepared statement) for free would be a smart thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. For future situations, how did you know CreateODBCDate didn't need sanitization?

Comment: it only returns date, so I don't see how you need to sanitize what it returns.